# Displaying multiple sea level scenarios?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, display, bathymetry

I'm trying to display a number of sea level scenarios to discuss landscape differences across time. I've created a CTM of the region now I need to display sea level at a number of reduced levels (e.g. -50m).

I've already tried extract by attribute using "value <=-50" which produces a number of error problems which seem to be related to the GDB, but I can't get round them. Could extract by mask be better?

Does anyone have a simpler or better way? In an ideal scenario I would like to display the final model with terrain changes displayed for the terrestrial data but the sea can be extracted as no data and displayed blue. However it can simply be a blue green display just showing coastline if that is the best way using ArcMap 10.3, Windows 8.

Comment: Have you tried [Raster Calculator](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/building-expressions-in-raster-calculator.htm)? This assumes you have Spatial Analyst

Comment: @Barbarossa I do have spatial analyst. Could this be used to extract direct to new raster? or to create shapefile to be used as a mask?

Comment: CTM == "Coastal Terrain Model", correct?  Is a CTM different in any way from a raster based DTM (Digital Terrain Model)?  Does it include bathymetric data?

Comment: @LeonB yes it a DTM. It does inc. data from bathymetry but its merged as a continuous dataset so displays as seemless, if that makes sense. The only difference is negative values exist in the elevation column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches you could use to extract portions of your surface model.  With Raster Calculator, you could extract cells based on values.  For instance, with the Con() statement you could do something like this:

```
Con("CTM_Raster" <= -50, 1, 0)
```

This will generate a new raster with a value of 1 for values less than -50, and 0 for those greater.  Of course, you will need to change the name of the raster.  This can then be used to create a polygon if desired.  And as I said, there are other ways.

## EDIT

If you wish to retain the original raster values, you can do the following:

```
Con("CTM_Raster" <= -50, "CTM_Raster", 0)
```

This will generate a raster with the original values below -50, and a value of 0 above.

Comment: I've just tried two techniques, your raster calculator and Raster Reclassify. Both produce good simple outputs. That said is there anyway to extract the data values for the area above -50 (in this example).

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: For anybody looking at this all three solutions mentioned work! @Barbarossa was most useful in this case for future use (i.e. if I need to run anymore spatial work through it). The use of two differently displayed rasters (@LeonB) maybe be the best for publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution by playing with the display.  (I think you would need to adjust display settings anyways to get what you're trying to do, regardless of whether you make another raster layer or change a range of cell values, right?)

This example uses the [National Elevation Dataset 10m](http://nationalmap.gov/elevation.html), but I display it twice, once to use the stretched symbology and hillshade for the land, and then overlay that with a layer using classified symbology.  The classes are set to elevation values where the break is at the elevation you want to display sea level.  Color the class below sea level blue (or your choice), and the above sea level set to "No Color" so that the stretched value, "land" layer shows through.

1. Display the CTM or DEM/DTM twice:

[image]

2. Use classified symbology for the layer to show the sea level, set break at desired sea level elevation:
   [image]
3. Example 1:
   [image]
4. Example 2: (higher sea level)
   [image]